# Find Duplicates in a list of lists in python

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, unique

```
list = [[11], [21], [31], [41], [-11, 21], [11, -21],
        [-21, 31], [21, -31], [-31, 41], [31, -41]]
```

Output should contain

```
list_unique = [11,21,31,41]
```

How to write a code for this in python ?

Comment: This is very unclear. Why are `-31` and `-21` not included in your output when they are also present more than once in the input?

Comment: This is an arrangement problem, so ideally 31 and -31 are same and are duplicates, so I just need to output 11,21,31,41 though they appear with negations.

Comment: Then that should be in your question. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) – you need to explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve, how you've tried to solve it, and what problem you're having with your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
unique_list = []
for i in list:
    for k in i:
        if not abs(k) in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(abs(k))
```

Comment: Sorry. I missed positive/negative

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the output here is the code below:

```
input_list = [[11], [21], [31], [41], [-11, 21], [11, -21], [-21, 31], [21, -31], [-31, 41], [31, -41]]

def get_explode_list(input_list):
    explode_list = []
    for inner_list in input_list:
        for item in inner_list:
            explode_list.append(item)
    return explode_list

explode_list = get_explode_list(input_list)
dictionary = {}
for x in explode_list:
    value = dictionary.get(x,0)
    value = value+1
    dictionary[x] = value

def get_final_list(dictionary):
    final_list = []
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        if(value > 1 and key >= 0):
            final_list.append(key)
    return final_list

final_list = get_final_list(dictionary)
```

final_list = [31, 41, 11, 21]
You can use this code if your input list is not int just take out the 'and key >= 0' in get_final_list method and run
Please vote the answer if you find it helpful.